# SQL GroupBy with Case

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm pretty new to SQL, I'm trying to write a query to groupBy based on conditions.
What I want is
-> For marketplace CA & MX, sum amount based on MARKETPLACE & TRANSACTION_TYPE (CODE would always be the same)
-> For marketplace BR, sum both amount and local amount based on MARKETPLACE & TRANSACTION_TYPE & CONSUMPTION_TYPE

But it gives me exception: Service: AmazonAthena; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException when I ran below query.

```
SELECT 
    CASE rae.TRANSACTION_MARKETPLACE_ID 
        WHEN '123456' THEN 'CA'
        WHEN '234567' THEN 'MX'
        WHEN '345678' THEN 'BR'
        END as MARKETPLACE,
    TRANSACTION_TYPE, SUM(AMOUNT) as AMOUNT, CODE,
    IF (TRANSACTION_MARKETPLACE_ID = '345678',
        SUM(rae.LOCAL_AMOUNT)
        ) as LOCAL_AMOUNT,
    IF (
        rae.TRANSACTION_MARKETPLACE_ID = '345678',
        LOCAL_CODE
        ) as LOCAL_CODE,
    IF (
        rae.TRANSACTION_MARKETPLACE_ID = '345678',
        CONSUMPTION_TYPE
        ) as CONSUMPTION_TYPE
FROM xxxTable as rae
WHERE MODEL = 'MODEL_1'
    AND TRANSACTION_MARKETPLACE_ID IN ('123456', '234567', '345678')
    AND (TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'TYPE_1' OR TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'TYPE_2' OR (TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'TYPE_3' AND ALLOW_CLAWBACK = TRUE))
    AND TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN timestamp '2023-09-01' AND timestamp '2023-09-30'
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN MARKETPLACE = 'BR'
         THEN TRANSACTION_MARKETPLACE_ID, TRANSACTION_TYPE, CODE, LOCAL_CODE, CONSUMPTION_TYPE END),
         (CASE WHEN MARKETPLACE IN ('BR', 'CA') THEN TRANSACTION_MARKETPLACE_ID, TRANSACTION_TYPE, CODE END);
```

Expected output would like

| MARKETPLACE | TRANSACTION_TYPE | AMOUNT | CODE | CONSUMPTION_TYPE | LOCAL_AMOUNT | LOCAL_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CA | TYPE_1 | xxx | USD |  |  |  |
| MX | TYPE_1 | xxx | USD |  |  |  |
| CA | TYPE_2 | xxx | USD |  |  |  |
| MX | TYPE_2 | xxx | USD |  |  |  |
| BR | TYPE_1 | xxx | USD | CON_TYPE_1 | xxx | USD |
| BR | TYPE_1 | xxx | USD | CON_TYPE_2 | xxx | USD |
| BR | TYPE_2 | xxx | USD | CON_TYPE_1 | xxx | USD |
| BR | TYPE_2 | xxx | USD | CON_TYPE_2 | xxx | USD |

It starts to give exception after I add cases within groupby. Can anyone give some ideas why ? Or would it be better to just separate into two queries ?
Also I want to select three more columns when TRANSACTION_MARKETPLACE_ID = '345678', I'm setting them separately, is there a way to set them together ?

Comment: I don't think CASE statements are supported in the GROUP BY clause.  What I'd probably try to do is update the IF statements in the SELECT clause to include an "else" value.  Just add "null" as a second argument to each.  Then update your GROUP BY clause to return all non-aggregated columns.  It's a little difficult to tell without being able to query the data myself.  I usually attempt to build up more complex queries field by field until I can isolate the field that is causing the issue.

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` expression is not working like you think it is. It is simply grouping by the single expression coming from the case statement which would be a tuple combining those fields.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it makes sense what you are trying to do in a single query. I've never seen conditional group by with a case as you were trying to do, and even less add more columns.

I'd suggest breaking this into 2 different queries. Then, you may even equalize the missing columns with empty values for the query that has less columns, and do a UNION between the 2 results. Something like:

```
SELECT 
    CASE rae.TRANSACTION_MARKETPLACE_ID 
        WHEN '123456' THEN 'CA'
        WHEN '234567' THEN 'MX'
        END as MARKETPLACE,
    TRANSACTION_TYPE, SUM(AMOUNT) as AMOUNT, CODE,
    0 as LOCAL_AMOUNT, '' as LOCAL_CODE, '' as CONSUMPTION_TYPE
from rae as rae
WHERE MODEL = 'MODEL_1'
    AND TRANSACTION_MARKETPLACE_ID IN ('123456', '234567')
    AND (TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'TYPE_1' OR TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'TYPE_2' OR (TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'TYPE_3' AND ALLOW_CLAWBACK = TRUE))
    AND TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN timestamp '2023-09-01' AND timestamp '2023-09-30'
 GROUP BY TRANSACTION_MARKETPLACE_ID, TRANSACTION_TYPE, CODE
UNION
 SELECT 
    'BR' as MARKETPLACE,
    TRANSACTION_TYPE, SUM(AMOUNT) as AMOUNT, CODE,
    SUM(rae.LOCAL_AMOUNT) as LOCAL_AMOUNT,LOCAL_CODE, CONSUMPTION_TYPE
from rae as rae
WHERE MODEL = 'MODEL_1'
    AND TRANSACTION_MARKETPLACE_ID ='345678'
    AND (TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'TYPE_1' OR TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'TYPE_2' OR (TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'TYPE_3' AND ALLOW_CLAWBACK = TRUE))
    AND TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN timestamp '2023-09-01' AND timestamp '2023-09-30'
 GROUP BY TRANSACTION_MARKETPLACE_ID, TRANSACTION_TYPE, CODE, LOCAL_CODE, CONSUMPTION_TYPE
```